# Could not find a declaration file for module 'laravel-vue-pagination'

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pagination

so i've already install laravel-vue pagination with

```
npm install laravel-vue pagination
```

also `npm install`, but when I declared it in my `resource/app.js` with

```
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));
```

it say cannot find  module `laravel-vue-pagination.common.js` in `node_modules`. what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this out.
First import **laravel-vue-pagination** like below.

```
import pagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';
```

then

```
Vue.component('pagination', pagination));
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a blank one for ease of use: create `laravel-vue-pagination.d.ts`

Then just declare the module:

```
declare module 'laravel-vue-pagination' {}
```

That's all you need to solve the error.